# Show first level children of a nested ul li using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an HTML file like this:

JS:

```
 function functionName(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var item = event.data.param;
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = item;
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("li").each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', {param: this.id}, functionName);
 });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="main">
<div id="tree">
<ul class="xyz">
  <li class="hide">AVC</li>
  <li class="hide">Anna</li>
  <li class="hide">Peter</li>
  <li id="foo1">Gary
  <ul class="xyz">
    <li class="hide">John</li>
    <li class="hide">Anna</li>
    <li id="foo2">Briton
    <ul class="xyz">
       <li class="hide">gg</li>
       <li class="hide">hh</li>
       <li id="foo3">Layla
       <ul class="xyz">
          <li class="hide">gg</li>
          <li class="hide">hh</li>
          <li id="foo4">Undertaker
          <ul class="xyz">
            <li class="hide">gg</li>
            <li class="hide">hh</li>
          </ul>
          </li>
       </ul>
       </li>
     </ul>
     </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  </div>

   <div id="list"></div>

   </div>
```

I have two div tags whose id is receptively `tree` and `list`. Tree div contains the nested `ul li` tags and each `li` have unique id.

I want to show the first level children of a `ul li` tag. For example, when I am clicking on `Gary`, it should show the first level children  ( `John, Anna, Britton`) in right `div i.e. list`.

Right now I am able to get the id of `ul li` element in `list` div when clicking any item.

How can I traverse the first level children of clicking element using jquery/javascript and display them in `list` div?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `find()` ,`> ul` selects the direct descendant

```
$('li[id^="foo"]').click(function(e){
e.stopPropagation();
var x = $(this).last().find(' > ul').clone().find('ul').remove().end();
console.log(x[0])
 $('#list').html(x);
 $('#list .hide').show();
});
```

simple demo : https://jsfiddle.net/sk30mwud/4/

Comment: no like this. I am able to do this thing that you are saying. I want to show the children of clicked item of a `tree` div to `list` div. I am trying to create a tree-list view using html and jquery/javascript.

Comment: yes like this but as you can see some of child is hidden in my html file. I want to see them also here.

Comment: like this : https://jsfiddle.net/sk30mwud/2/  or like this: https://jsfiddle.net/sk30mwud/3/ or https://jsfiddle.net/sk30mwud/4/?

Comment: you want only the first childrens of the branch see ^

Comment: I want to do it in third way that you have given. Thanks for answering.

Comment: hyperlink in last comment is not clickable.

Comment: Yes I want only the first branch of children.

Answer (score 1):

```
'$('#tree').on('click', 'li', function(){
     $(this).find('> ul > li').toggleClass('hide');
     return false;
})'
```

Comment: same as : $(this).children('ul').children('li');

Answer (score 1):

Can you please take a look at this approach:

It uses `.contents().get(0).nodeValue` to fetch the text present in child `li` nodes and not from its childerns if any.

```js
function functionName(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  var item = event.data.param;
  var names = [];

  $("#" + item).children("ul").children("li").each(function() {

    names.push($(this).contents().get(0).nodeValue);
  });

  $("#list").text(names.join(","));;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("li").each(function() {
    $(this).on('click', {
      param: this.id
    }, functionName);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
  <div id="tree">
    <ul class="xyz">
      <li class="hide">AVC</li>
      <li class="hide">Anna</li>
      <li class="hide">Peter</li>
      <li id="foo1">Gary
        <ul class="xyz">
          <li class="hide">John</li>
          <li class="hide">Anna</li>
          <li id="foo2">Briton
            <ul class="xyz">
              <li class="hide">gg</li>
              <li class="hide">hh</li>
              <li id="foo3">Layla
                <ul class="xyz">
                  <li class="hide">gg</li>
                  <li class="hide">hh</li>
                  <li id="foo4">Undertaker
                    <ul class="xyz">
                      <li class="hide">gg</li>
                      <li class="hide">hh</li>
                    </ul>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <div id="list"></div>

</div>
```